# CSS Topbar dropdown hover not wroking

Tags: html, css

I'm new to designing a web. Recently, I'am trying to design my web and putting Topbar with dropdown on hover, but it's not working. I'm using tutorial from W3School. I put my code below, maybe someone can tell me what did I do wrong. Thank you

```css
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="/try/front.php">Logo</a>
  <a class="active" href="rightMain.php">Name</a>
  <a class="active" href="rightPage1.php">Menu1</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `:hover` selector to the links in your dropdown.

In your case, simply add the following to your stylesheet.

```css
.dropdown-content a:hover{
  background: blue;
}
```

Full code snippet:

```css
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="/try/front.php">Logo</a>
  <a class="active" href="rightMain.php">Name</a>
  <a class="active" href="rightPage1.php">Menu1</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's solved, it was because I put fixed navbar, and when I remove it, the dropdown is working.

The code before was :

```
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
 }

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Then it become

```
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
 }

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```